# own RTE - get and set Style of Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, selection, rte

I have to build my own RTE with javascript or JQuery.
But I couldn't really find some good, commented, working example or tutorial just single pieces of code. But I don't want just a solution, I want understand what I'm doing!

I know how to make a selected Text bold (get the selection, create a range and then around it whit a b-tag or span-tag including a font-weight:bold.)

But how could I get all styles of any selection?

Example: text text text [//] text text text     ( [//] should be an image ) 
Now the user selects the text including the image, then the selected html code is like 'text text text  text text text'. Now i could not simple around the selected range with an tag.

Other example: aaa bbb **ccc** ddd
If i select 'cc d' I get the 'cc' like that: **cc** But when I'm selecting 'ccc' I get just 'ccc'. But I have to know all the styles of the selection to highlight the (eg. bold-) button.

To sum up, I've to know how I handle (getting) / setting of styles for selections.

I hope could help me!
Best Regards
Lenny

---

Here some code I actually have (but this code doesn't fix my problem anyway)

```
function getSelectedNodes_txt(){
var sel = window.getSelection();
try{var frag=sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()}catch(e){return(false);}
var tempspan = document.createElement("span");
tempspan.appendChild(frag);
console.log(tempspan);
window.selnodes = tempspan.childNodes;
var output = ''
for(var i=0, u=selnodes.length;i<u;i++){
    if (typeof selnodes[i].tagName !== 'undefined'){
      output += "A "+selnodes[i].tagName+" was found";
      output += " - Containing: "+selnodes[i].textContent+"\n";
    }else{
        output += "Some text was found: '"+selnodes[i].textContent+"'";
        output += " - Parent: '"+selnodes[i].parentNode.tagName+"'\n";
     }
    //do something cool with each element here...
}
return(output)
```

}

Comment: Any code? No code, No Answer!

Comment: What code do you want? I don't know how to code it. that's why I need help. Or do yuu want the piece of code I tried to use for the selection? I'll add it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pointer: `execCommand` allows you to query the boldness or italicness of the text at the caret position.

Comment: `document.execCommand()` also acts on the current selection, not just the caret.

Comment: Could you give me any examples? I want to get any style (also red background or yellow border). Hope that's possible.